# Sharepoint 2010 VB.net adding to list

Tags: vb.net, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-designer

Hey all i am looking to add some data to a list in my sharepoint site.

The following code is what i am trying to use:

```
Dim siteUrl As String = "http://thespsite/sandbox/"
Dim clientContext As New ClientContext(siteUrl)
Dim oList As List = clientContext.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("demoT")
Dim listCreationInformation As New ListItemCreationInformation()
Dim oListItem As ListItem = oList.AddItem(listCreationInformation)

oListItem("Title") = "testing this out"
oListItem("Priority") = "(2) Normal"
oListItem("AssignedTo") = "Lastname, Firstname"
oListItem.Update()
clientContext.ExecuteQuery()
```

My list is called **demoT** and the fields **Title, Priority and Assigned To** are all fields i wish to add to the list. Of course the Lastname, Firstname is filled out with a actual name from the SPDB.

However, this is the error i get:

```
An exception of type 'Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ServerException' 
occurred in Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime.dll but was not 
handled in user code

Additional information: Invalid data has been used to update the 
list item. The field you are trying to update may be read only.
```

I do know that Comments exist since i see it on my list... just don't know why it wont allow me to add? If i comment that part of the code out and run it, it posts to the list just fine.

The Sharepoint Designer HTML code for the Assigned To part is:

```
<SharePoint:FormField runat="server" id="ff2{$Pos}" ControlMode="New" 
    FieldName="AssignedTo" __designer:bind="{ddwrt:DataBind('i',concat('ff2',$Pos),
       'Value','ValueChanged','ID', ddwrt:EscapeDelims(string(@ID)),'@AssignedTo')}"/>
<SharePoint:FieldDescription runat="server" id="ff2description{$Pos}" 
    FieldName="AssignedTo" ControlMode="New"/>
```

What could i be missing to prevent it from adding that field?

Answer (score 0):

My first guess is that the format for your "Assigned To" field is wrong. See here to get started:

https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/21168/setting-user-column-value-via-client-object-model